# JavaScript recreate element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a user viewer for my friend's Minecraft Classic Server (in-dev version [here](http://ns2.nuclearstorm.net/nucsto/user.php?name=LemonLake)) and below the skin is a slider. It is intended to be a zoom slider, and I need it to change the scale of the skin. The skin viewer and slider work perfectly fine; however, my trouble is in the element. It appears that I can only draw to my `<img>` once (code attached), and I'm not sure how to resolve that. My current plan is to delete the element and create it again, but I'm not sure how to even do that. Does anyone have any resources, tips, or information regarding this?

```
Page source: http://pastebin.com/R4qqTVz8
Modified mcSkinRenderer.js (courtesy of Joran de Raaff): http://ns2.nuclearstorm.net/nucsto/mcSkinRenderer.js
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: @putvande So is it a better idea to re-create the element hard-coded, storing the name in a PHP variable and accessing that, or should I copy the element's data such as src and store that in a JS variable?

Comment: This line `"SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name='" . $_GET['name'] . "'", $db` is dangerous. It allows for SQL injection attacks. You can remedy this by using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what's happening with your code.

When you run renderMCSkins the first time, it looks through the page and finds all images with the class of 'skin'. It then REPLACES those images with canvas elements and renders the image into the new canvas. When you use the slider it runs that renderMCskins function again, only this time there are no longer images on the page with that class name because they have already been converted to canvas elements.

You have two options.

First, do as you initially thought and DELETE all instances of that canvas element, then replace it with the initial image, and run renderMCSkins with the new zoom value.

Second, you can update the mcSkinRenderer.js to include some kind of an update function to make changes to the canvas elements that have already been rendered.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed it would be something like this, and you have pointed me in the correct direction. You've also saved me days of extensive staring at the same characters.

Comment: No worries. I also supplied an update function. Let me know if it works. You'll noticed I changed very little from the renderMCSkins function. Previously renderMCSkins would ONLY return images with the class of 'skin' this will seek out canvas elements and replace those instead.

Comment: Ah, very useful indeed :) Thanks once again

Comment: I had to remove the skin.complete if statement to get it to work, and I was met with this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'getAttribute'` @Tyler

Comment: Yes I apologize, .complete is a property of image, one that I don't think canvas shares. Sorry for the oversight. Is everything good now?

Comment: Not quite, however I may have a solution. If it is an existing canvas, I do not need to create a new one. Instead, I can just clear it, set it's new size and draw to it again, right?

Comment: That's correct, but it's a little more complicated, so I was trying to keep it simple. I've updated my function, give it a shot. If it doesn't work for you then when I have time I may be able to help by writing an update function that edits the existing canvas.

Comment: Still no luck :( Been fiddling with the code, I think something is going wrong with finding the canvases.